# How can we bypass salesforce login screen for authentication by custom login screen?

Tags: ios, react-native, salesforce, salesforce-mobile-sdk

We need authentication functionality without using salesforce login page, we need our own custom page for login​

As facebook provide option for authentication by using their own button or we can also use their function over our custom button

Note: we are using salesforce mobilesdk and application is based on reactnative.

Answer (score 0):

If you are integrating Salesforce Mobile SDK then salesforce won't encourage you to access their features without making secure checks.

Mobile SDK includes a complete implementation of Salesforce Connected App Policy, so that all users can access their data securely and easily. It supports SAML and advanced authentication flows so that administrators always have full control over data access.

Below are the major features of SDK which salesforce provide after their authentication.

```
=> SmartStore Encrypted Database
=> Mobile Sync
=> Mobile Services
=> Salesforce Communities
```

When you create a native app using the forceios utility, your project starts as a fully functioning app. This app lets you log in to a Salesforce org, and then it displays live Salesforce data.
So it's not possible to skip login screen when using Salesforce Mobile SDK.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/preface_intro.htm